# How do you change terminal font size in OSX withOUT changing the terminal window size as well?

Tags: macos, terminal

In OSX, changing font size in terminal by hitting CMD and ('+' or '-') changes the window size as well. THis is annoying as I have to always resize the window back to the correct size.

Is there any way to keep the window size constrained during font size changing?

The workaround I have is to use a windows manager such as Moom to resize the window quickly after each font size change, but I'd love to know if I can eliminate the window re-sizing step altogether. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize the Terminal preference settings to set the font size:

**Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Text > Font**

There is no built-in way to resize the text in an individual window without resizing the window: Terminal preserves the row and column counts whenever possible, since the terminal dimensions normally affect the behavior of programs running in the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

## In addition to the correct answer:

#### Propagate Terminal Settings after using CMD +/- or Resizing:

- Simple Save Settings: Menu: Shell > Use Settings as Default
  ```
  Stores the current terminal (with resized window and font) settings 
  to the current profile. It *does* make that profile the default for 
  all future terminal windows, but this can easily be changed in the 
  Profiles tab under Menu: Terminal > Preferences.
  ```

- Export Settings: Menu: Shell > Export
- Import Settings: Menu: Shell > Import
  ```
  Save the current terminal settings (Resized Window, Font, etc) to a 
  saved profile and import as new profile.
  ```

#### Mass Assignment of Terminal Settings:

- Menu: Terminal > Preferences > Profiles
- Shift+click or CMD+click - select the profiles you want to mass-assign
- Change the window size (on Window tab), font (on text tab) or any other supported setting
  ```
  Enables quick changes to several Profiles
  ```

#### BONUS: Article on Various beautification tips at [osxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/)